# VS Code Powershell "←]633;P;IsWindows=True"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am working on a web application using Angular in Vs code.
I ran into some errors while I am fixing them in the process my vscode is bricked after a couple of minutes it return to its normal state but some weird beep sounds raised so i restarted my Laptop.

When I opened VS code again beep sound repeated and my powershell is showing some weird text

So, I thought the error this is due to some misconfigurations in my vscode and I uninstalled VScode ,deleted all related data

After installation the same weird text with beep sounds appeared again

The weird text

````
←]633;P;IsWindows=True
633;A633;P;Cwd=D:\user\website\quizPS D:\chiru\website\quiz> 633;B
←]633;C```
````

Comment: This looks like (malformed?) ANSI terminal control escape sequences.

Comment: I've created issue in vscode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160419

Answer (score 10):

As @meganrogge said in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160419 setting `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled` to `false` fixes this

Comment: This works, but I had to also exit the terminal for each workspace (by entering `exit` in the terminal) after changing the setting. Starting a new terminal after that does not cause the beeps or escape sequences anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I had in the settings `Terminal > Integrated: Windows Enable Conpty` (setting ID `terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty`) disabled. After re-enabling it again (which is the default) the problem went away for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have scala sbt installed? it does not work well with ms power shell. On Windows it can be used via git bash for example. Go to your user vs code settings and adjust so following terminal integration will be active

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":{"Git Bash":{"path":"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"},  },
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
```

the close your ms power shell tab in vs code terminal panel and add new bash one.

Comment: thanks ,after reinstalling powershell the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is a problem with powershell so i reinstalled my powershell it worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:

Ctrl + Mayus + P

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I uninstalled VS Code and installed again and the issue was resolved for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).