# VS Code Powershell shows "←]633;P;IsWindows=True" with beep

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254344/vs-code-powershell-%e2%86%90633piswindows-true) exact problem with that exact words in vs code. I tried reinstalling vs code but that doesn't work and i also tried reinstalling powershell but that also does not work.

This does not happen when i use windows powershell,cmd,bash as terminal so it's a problem with powershell (version 7.2.5) i am using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had in the settings `Terminal > Integrated: Windows Enable Conpty` (setting ID `terminal.integrated.windowsEnableConpty`) disabled. After re-enabling it again (which is the default) the problem went away for me.

(I posted the same answer on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254344/vs-code-powershell-%e2%86%90633piswindows-true), but as this duplicate is findable on Google and not tagged here, I'm posting the same answer)

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution!  I actually had to leave the Terminal Integrated Windows Enable Conpty setting off (unchecked) to fix this issue.