vscode trying but failing to use my uv venv
I have the following code in main.py:
import pymupdf

print(f"pymupdf version is: {pymupdf.__version__}")

I can create a python3.12 environment with pymupdf installed and run it from my (kubuntu24.04) shell without issues, with the following commands (showing shell log after each >command):
>uv --version
uv 0.4.17

>uv init --no-pin-python
Initialized project `askliz2`

>uv venv --python 3.12.6 
Using CPython 3.12.6
Creating virtual environment at: .venv
Activate with: source .venv/bin/activate

>source .venv/bin/activate 
askliz2>uv add pymupdf 
Resolved 3 packages in 281ms
Installed 2 packages in 11ms
 + pymupdf==1.24.10
 + pymupdfb==1.24.10

askliz2>python main.py
pymupdf version is: 1.24.10

However, when I launch vscode from this folder with my uv venv activated with code ., and then highlight the line import pymupdf and hit shift+enter to run it in the integrated terminal, I get the following vscode integrated terminal output:
/home/max/askliz2/.venv/bin/python 
Python 3.12.6 (main, Sep  9 2024, 22:11:19) [Clang 18.1.8 ] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
]633;E;exit()]633;D;0]633;A>>> ]633;B]633;Cimport pymupdf
]633;E;import pymupdf]633;D;0]633;A>>> ]633;B]633;C

Things I've tried so far:

upgrading uv version
hosing and re-installing vscode
installing different python versions (e.g. 3.12.0, 3.12.6, 3.9)
right-clicking to clear terminal and kill terminal and then trying again.

When I use the command pallet to select python interpreter, it shows me it's trying to use Python 3.12.6('.venv') ./.venv/bin/python, as it should be, and as the vscode integrated logs above already indicate.

That almost looks like it's copying escape sequences (ANSI/VT100/etc) into the terminal as part of your shift-enter (with sequences like ]633; followed by one of A-E). Does simply entering the import statement in the console by hand work? If so, there's something wrong with what shift-enter is doing. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254344/vs-code-powershell-%E2%86%90633piswindows-true, this also shows that 633 stuff. Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160419

thanks, that definitely sounds right to me. to answer your question, after restarting vscode, and entering just source .venv/bin/activate and then python from the integrated (bash) terminal to launch python, I indeed get the same output:
Python 3.12.6 (main, Sep  9 2024, 22:11:19) [Clang 18.1.8 ] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
]633;E;exit()]633;D;0]633;A>>> ]633;B]633;C


Interestingly, the GitHub issues I found from your links all reference this issue on windows machines, while I'm on an Ubuntu laptop.
